# Randomize batch variables

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to make a Yahtzee game and I need to randomize number 1-6 in order to make it echo the specific dice face.

```
    :gameplay
    cls
    pause
    SET /A dice=%RANDOM% %%6+1
    if %dice%==1
    echo %dice1a%
    echo %dice1b%
    echo %dice1c%
    echo %dice1d%
    echo %dice1e%
    echo %dice1g%
    pause
```

This is the code I developed. Its not completed yet, this was just a test of the randomizer. Every time I run this, it gets to the first pause, then it quits the program.  If you guys know what the problem is, can you tell me, and also I was wondering if it was possible to store multiline variable so I don't have to constantly echo multiple variables. If you guys know anything please tell me. Thanks

EDIT:
I tried what you suggested and did this:

```
    :gameplay
    cls
    pause
    SET /A dice=%RANDOM% %%6+1
    if %dice%=1
    echo Hi
    pause
    echo %dice1a%
    echo %dice1b%
    echo %dice1c%
    echo %dice1d%
    echo %dice1e%
    echo %dice1g%
    pause
```

It didn't follow through to the 2nd pause so I think the variable isn't set properly. I barely noticed this time that it says invalid command syntax right before it quits. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Are you sure it gets to the first pause only? Looks like it falls through. Put some more echoes in there.

Comment: try again with `if %dice%==1`

Comment: It still says that there is an invalid syntax a split second before the program quits.

Comment: Your IF statement is totally invalid syntax. Take the time to read documentation on the various commands. Also, your logic is a mess.

Comment: Now I am a little confused because I tried another echo right before SET /A dice=%RANDOM% %%6+1 so idk what is going wrong.

Comment: yes put the echoes right after the if like so: `if %dice%==1 echo rolled 1` and run the script in a terminal so you can read the errors

Comment: If you know that my IF statement is a total mess, and my logic odd, then can you please tell me how to do it. I started this project with the knowledge gained from looking at other peoples programs, not really making some myself. I guess you don't understand that I am a noob about coding.

Comment: When I did what you said, Yacc, it said I am "missing operator" which gets me thinking that maybe I need to import a module at the beginning of my program. I will get the rest sorted out tomorrow but thank you so much.

Comment: There's no module missing. Maybe it's better to copy/paste the error into your question and update it with the script you have so far. Run a terminal with Start-Execute cmd and cd into your work directory, then type the name of your script. So you can read the error without the window closing.

Comment: In your second attempt you are missing an equal sign in the if statement which is the reason it quits. Not the setting of the variable.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys I figured it out, I just was missing the double and quadruple spaces as well as the parenthesis in the if then statement.

```
    SET /A dice=%RANDOM% %%6 +1
      if %dice%==1 (
        echo %dice1a%
        echo %dice1b%
        echo %dice1c%
        echo %dice1d%
        echo %dice1e%
        echo %dice1f%
        echo %dice1g%
      )
```

I really appreciate everyone who attempted to help me, even if it was just me being stupid, and I really appreciate yacc for helping me the whole way.  If you want my game once its finished, I will copy it on to the about me section.

Comment: Looks like you tackled it and +1 for reporting. Let us know if the game is ready.

Comment: This is a link to my new question about my Yahtzee game.